# Properties of Estimators

Tags: statistics

Suppose I have the following pdf $f(y;\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta^2}ye^{-y/\theta}$ and I am told that $E(Y)=2\theta$ and $Var(Y)=2\theta^2$.

> Is $\frac{1}{2}\bar{Y}$ an unbiased estimator of $\theta$?
>    Is $\frac{1}{2}\bar{Y}$ an efficient estimator of $\theta$?

First, is it unbiased.  Consider the following:

$E(\hat{\theta})=E(\frac{1}{2}\bar{Y})=\frac{1}{2}E(\bar{Y})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\theta=\theta$  Hence $E(\hat{\theta})=\theta$.  Thus this is unbiased.

$Var(\hat{\theta})=\frac{1}{4}Var(\bar{Y})=\frac{2\theta^2}{4}=\frac{1}{4}Var(\frac{1}{n}\sum Y)=\frac{1}{4n^2}\sum(Var(Y))=\frac{2n\theta^2}{4n^2}=\frac{\theta^2}{2n}$.  Give that the Cramer-Rao bound of this PDF is $\frac{\theta^2}{2n}$ we see this is not efficient.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: IIRC, the Cramer-Rao Bound is a *lower bound*, and any estimator that satisfies it is called an efficient estimator. Your calculations, which are correct, in fact show that the estimator *is* efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your work concluding that $\hat \theta = \bar Y/2$ is unbiased, is correct.  Your calculation of the variance is confusing.  I would write it as:  $$\operatorname{Var}[\hat \theta] = \operatorname{Var}[\bar Y/2] = \frac{1}{4n^2} \operatorname{Var}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right] = \frac{1}{4n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}[Y_i] = \frac{1}{4n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n 2\theta^2 = \frac{2n\theta^2}{4n^2} = \frac{\theta^2}{2n}.$$

Now, to calculate the Cramer-Rao lower bound, the Fisher information is given by $$\mathcal I(\theta) = -\operatorname{E}\left[\frac{\partial^2 \ell(\theta \mid \boldsymbol y)}{\partial \theta^2} \right],$$ where $\boldsymbol y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ is the sample, and $\ell$ is the log-likelihood function of $\theta$ given $\boldsymbol y$.  The likelihood is $$\mathcal L(\theta \mid \boldsymbol y) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_Y(y_i \mid \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{y_ie^{-y_i/\theta}}{\theta^2} = \frac{e^{-n\bar y/\theta}}{\theta^{2n}} \prod_{i=1}^n y_i.$$  The log-likelihood is therefore $$\ell(\theta \mid \boldsymbol y) = -\frac{n\bar y}{\theta} - 2n \log \theta + \sum_{i=1}^n \log y_i.$$  Taking the second derivative with respect to $\theta$ gives $$\frac{d^2 \ell}{d \theta^2} = -\frac{2n \bar y}{\theta^3} + \frac{2n}{\theta^2}.$$  And since we previously calculated $\operatorname{E}[\bar Y] = 2\theta$, we find $$\mathcal I (\theta) = \frac{2n(2\theta)}{\theta^3} - \frac{2n}{\theta^2} = \frac{2n}{\theta^2},$$ consequently the Cramer-Rao lower bound for any unbiased estimator $w(\theta)$ of $\theta$ is $$\operatorname{Var}[w(\theta)] \ge \mathcal I^{-1}(\theta) = \frac{\theta^2}{2n}.$$  Since the estimator $w(\theta) = \hat \theta = \bar Y/2$ is unbiased, and achieves this lower bound, it is the UMVUE of $\theta$, and is the **finite-sample efficient estimator** among all unbiased estimators of $\theta$.